# Error in SSIS - Parameters cannot be extracted when parsing query, syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am building an SSIS package to select some data as XML and export it to a flat file. I've running it via a for each loop, I have a sql execute task to select all records in a table and then loop through each one to create a single XML file.

Here is the SQL statement I am trying to execute as part of the data flow in the OLE DB Source Editor. The select is inside another SELECT (...) AS XML_TEXT to make the output to be text

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SalesCode, ProductName, ManufacturingSite, Country, Language, Status, RevisionDate, ArchiveDate, PFFileName, XMLFileName, Version
FROM ir_cp_connect_data
WHERE (id = ?)
FOR XML RAW ('Data'), ROOT ('Sales'), ELEMENTS XSINIL)
AS XML_TEXT
```

I've tried to enter it direct as a SQL command and also in a variable. When I enter it directly into as a command, it errors saying it cannot parse the query, giving syntax error, permission violation or other non specific error.

When I switch it out to be a variable in data access mode, it errors with a long error message,

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLD DB Error has occurred, Error Code 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.

Again it then goes on to list 'syntax error, permission violation or other non specific error.'

If I run the select statement in SQL Management Studio it works, albeit I substitute the `id = ?` for `id = @id` and declare the @id in and assign it a value.

I'm working with VS2008 and SQL Server 2008R2.

I feel I am missing something very obvious but I cannot put my finger on it. If I drop the opening SELECT (..) AS XML_TEXT, the query parses fine, but the output is System.Byte[] which is no good for the flat file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The code you've posted isn't valid SQL. Having said that SSIS parameter parser can only parse the most basic of parameters. Anything complicated it can't handle

Comment: Oh.. yes it is valid SQL but still complicated for the parser. In these situations use expressions to build up the SQL dynamically